# Error ActiveRecord::PendingMigrationError

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, server

I am following Michael Hartl's book and I am getting this error when I run the server:

[image]

I am getting ActiveRecord::PendingMigrationError when I run the server, this shows up:

Migrations are pending. To resolve this issue, run: bin/rails  db:migrate RAILS_ENV=development

Please I've been stuck in this error for so long.

When I type `$ RAILS_ENV=development rake db:migrate` I get this error:

> == 20161209073230 AddActivationToUsers: migrating =============================
>   -- add_column(:users, :activation_digest, :string) rake aborted! StandardError: An error has occurred, this and all later migrations
>   canceled:
>
> SQLite3::SQLException: duplicate column name: activation_digest: ALTER
>   TABLE "users" ADD "activation_digest" varchar
>   (required)>' Tasks: TOP => db:migrate (See full trace by running task
>   with --trace)

test/mailers/previews/user_mailer_preview.rb

> UserMailerPreview < ActionMailer::Preview
>
> # Preview this email at
>   http://localhost:3000/rails/mailers/user_mailer/account_activation
>   def account_activation
>       user = User.first
>       user.activation_token = User.new_token
>       UserMailer.account_activation(user)   end
>
> # Preview this email at
>   http://localhost:3000/rails/mailers/user_mailer/password_reset   def
>   password_reset
>       UserMailer.password_reset   end
>
> end

Schema.rb:

```
# This file is auto-generated from the current state of the database. Instead
# of editing this file, please use the migrations feature of Active Record to
# incrementally modify your database, and then regenerate this schema definition.
#
# Note that this schema.rb definition is the authoritative source for your
# database schema. If you need to create the application database on another
# system, you should be using db:schema:load, not running all the migrations
# from scratch. The latter is a flawed and unsustainable approach (the more migrations
# you'll amass, the slower it'll run and the greater likelihood for issues).
#
# It's strongly recommended that you check this file into your version control system.

ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20161123005710) do

  create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.string   "email"
    t.datetime "created_at",        null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",        null: false
    t.string   "password_digest"
    t.string   "remember_digest"
    t.string   "activation_digest"
    t.index ["email"], name: "index_users_on_email", unique: true   end

end
```

Latest migration is
 db/migrate/[timestamp]_add_activation_to_users.rb:

```
class AddActivationToUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def change
    add_column :users, :activation_digest, :string
    add_column :users, :activated, :boolean, default: falserao
    add_column :users, :activated_at, :datetime
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok the answer is very simple!Just try migrating your DB to version=0 with command: `rake db:migrate VERSION=0`

and then run  `rake db:migrate`

Answer (score 1):

The correct command to apply unapplied migrations is `RAILS_ENV=development rake db:migrate`

Comment: I still get the same error:                                                                                             == 20161209073230 AddActivationToUsers: migrating =============================
-- add_column(:users, :activation_digest, :string)
rake aborted!
StandardError: An error has occurred, this and all later migrations canceled:

SQLite3::SQLException: duplicate column name: activation_digest: ALTER TABLE "users" ADD "activation_digest" varchar

Comment: Why are you trying to add already existing column? If that add_column is the only call in that failing migration you better delete that migration entirely. Otherwise just comment out that line and retry.

Comment: Wait you might be onto something. Which file should I go to, to comment that line that you are talking about? I'm sorry, I'm completely new to Ruby

Comment: the migration files are in db/migrate and search for file named 20161209073230_...

Comment: When I comment the line " add_column :users, :activation_digest, :string" I get this : == 20161209073230 AddActivationToUsers: migrating =============================
-- add_column(:users, :activated, :boolean, {:default=>false})
rake aborted!
StandardError: An error has occurred, this and all later migrations canceled:

SQLite3::SQLException: duplicate column name: activated: ALTER TABLE "users" ADD "activated" boolean DEFAULT 'f'

Comment: well, not sure how this happened, but looks like this migration was already executed but not marked in database as executed. This is a hack of course but you can manually mark it as executed by inserting a record into the schema_migrations table. Ready for that? Otherwise if you don't have any data to lose it's easier to reset your database and run all migrations again.

Comment: Yes I'm ready, what do I have to do. The migrations are all done by michael hartl. I'm ready for whatever it takes to fix this issue

Comment: run rails db and execute the following statement:
insert into schema_migrations (version) values ('20161209073230');

Comment: Run rails db? or run rails db:migrate?

Comment: rails db. this is a tool to manipulate the development database.

Comment: I did rails db and this appeared: SQLite version 3.8.2 2013-12-06 14:53:30
Enter ".help" for instructions
Enter SQL statements terminated with a ";"

Comment: paste this: insert into schema_migrations (version) values ('20161209073230');

and you're done. then try to run "rails server"

Comment: I did exactly what you said and this is what appeared:                           Error: UNIQUE constraint failed: schema_migrations.version

Answer (score 0):

This just means that you have a migration pending. When you create a new migration

```
railas g migration MigrationName
```

it means that it changes something in the database schema or the layout of your database. In order to commit that change, you have to run:

```
bin/rails db:migrate
```

This will look into your migration file and apply it to your databse. Once the migration is done, you can run server as usual again.

```
rails server
```

If you have more question, I recommend reading the migration documentation that Rails published:

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_migrations.html

Comment: But when I do that, I get this error:                                                          == 20161209073230 AddActivationToUsers: migrating =============================
-- add_column(:users, :activation_digest, :string)
rails aborted!
StandardError: An error has occurred, this and all later migrations canceled:

SQLite3::SQLException: duplicate column name: activation_digest: ALTER TABLE "users" ADD "activation_digest" varchar

Comment: It seems you already have a column named activation_digest. It is hard for me to tell you where to look. Do you have the project online ? I could check it and help you more. If not, check in your previous migrations and look if you have already an activation_digest column. If possible paste the content of the migration here.

Comment: You have two errors. One, rejection of your rake command, is caused by the other. The other says you are trying to create a column that's already been created. Post your most recent migration file and your schema and I or someone else will pinpoint the error.

Comment: OK I posted both my schema file and my latest migration, if you can please tell me what's wrong and what I can do to fix it

Answer (score 0):

> SQLite3::SQLException: **duplicate column name: activation_digest:**
>
> (The following is the SQL command that actually modifies the db):
>
> ALTER TABLE "users" ADD "activation_digest"

The SQL command reads like plain English.  Somehow one of your migrations is doing something a previous migration already did, namely adding the `activation_digest` column to your users table in the db.  If you look in the directory `db/migrate/`, you will see all your migration files.  If you open one of them up, you should sort of be able to tell what it is doing.  So look at all your migration files and find the two migrations that both add the `activation_digest` column.  If the two migration files are identical, then you need to delete one--but take the following steps before deleting a migration:

https://www.baserails.com/questions/i-messed-up-while-generating-my-migration-how-can-i-undo-it

Also check out the section `Rolling Back` in the Rails Guide:

http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_migrations.html#reverting-previous-migrations

If for some reason you don't have two identical migration files that both add the `activation_digest` column, e.g one of the migration files does something additionally, then you need to figure out what steps in the tutorial that you did wrong, then rollback to the last migration that you know is correct.  Finally, follow the steps in the tutorial again for generating the subsequent migrations.

Answer (score 0):

It seems your users table already have a column named activation_digest. Remove the `add_column` line where the column is added from the migration file and run the migration again.

I think this migration file should work:

```
class AddActivationToUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def change
    add_column :users, :activated, :boolean, default: false
    add_column :users, :activated_at, :datetime
  end
end
```

Comment: When I do what you sat above, this shows up, {== 20161211035304 AddActivationToUsers: migrating =============================
-- falserao()
rails aborted!
StandardError: An error has occurred, this and all later migrations canceled:

undefined local variable or method `falserao' for #<AddActivationToUsers:0x00000004884ad8>}

Comment: The problem is with the string `falserao` on the migration. I blindly copied your example and reproduced it on my answer. 
Change it to `false` and it should work. I'll edit my answer to fix the typo.

Comment: But then this occurs: {== 20161211035304 AddActivationToUsers: migrating =============================
-- add_column(:users, :activated, :boolean, {:default=>false})
rails aborted!
StandardError: An error has occurred, this and all later migrations canceled:

SQLite3::SQLException: duplicate column name: activated: ALTER TABLE "users" ADD "activated" boolean DEFAULT 'f'}

Comment: Can you post the output of the command `rake db:migration:status`, please?